# `mcrypt_create_iv` Stalls, But Only Through Apache

Tags: php, mcrypt, gentoo

My local installation of PHP started doing this recently, but I don't know what changed and could have started this. It completely stalls out with 100% CPU utilization when I call `mycrypt_create_iv`, but *only* when that's called by Apache. When I call it from the CLI, it returns almost instantly. My test file is as follows:

```
<?php echo mcrypt_create_iv(16, MCRYPT_DEV_URANDOM);
```

The values are, of course, what the function was getting called with when I discovered this issue. This issue happens with either PHP 5.5 or 5.6, so I don't think it's the specific PHP version.

I'm running Gentoo Linux, so it's possible that the root cause was a build issue, but I've rebuilt libmcrypt, PHP, and Apache to no effect.

Comment: How is Apache configured to run PHP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some experimentation, I got it.

I did not have `APACHE2_MPMS` set in `make.conf`, so it defaulted to the `worker` MPM. I set it to use `prefork` and this problem cleared away.

I did have the `threads` USE flag set, which conflicted with `prefork` and PHP, so I removed that use flag. With my profile, that meant that most packages with that flag still had it set, but `php` and `mod_php` disabled.

Answer (score 1):

seems a bug(https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=69833) of php which fixed in 5.6.13